# Why are my GTmetrix scores different in different locations?

Tags: seo, performance, gtmetrix

The GTmetrix score of my website when tested in Vancouver differ from the results in Mumbai by a whopping 4 seconds! Different locations are giving me different results. What's happening here and which score must I take to be true? I use the Jetpack CDN for images.

Answer (score 1):

Because the distance between you and the server matters. More distance means more time required to obtain the sources to render the website.

Comment: But India is closer to my location than Vancouver is.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the CDN has a datacenter closer to Vancouver. It could also be non-image assets that are not delivered via your CDN, for example, some 3rd party code. The network in India is generally speaking not as fast as in Canada.

In any case, it is very common to see different latencies among user locations. If your user base is mostly in India then it may make sense to optimize.